How to perform maintenance/troubleshoot of heat pump functionality of water heater?
This is a follow up question to my previous question: Is this the right way to change heating element for hybrid electric water heater?

It is a hybrid electric water heater(model: GEH50DFEJSR). I want to make sure heat pump part of this water heater is working to its full performance. Have gone through this manual and cleaned the filter as it says but I am not sure on what else I can do to make sure optimal performance of heat pump.
Here are my questions:

I have never seen water coming out of condensate drain overflow valve. Does it mean it is all good?
Not sure how I can check if condensation drain line connection is clogged. Should I run a scope into it to see? I checked the other end of it, which is draining to outside of my house and it seems okay.
Can I open red panel in the below picture to perform any kind of troubleshoot? or this is beyond diy thing?
What else I can do to make sure heat pump is doing its thing?
One other option I was thinking of was to switch to heat pump mode and see if it is able to produce hot water at all. If it does, it means all good??



Does water come out the condensation drain (not overflow) outside where it goes when the heater is operating?  Is the exhaust air blowing out of the unit cooler than room temperature?

Is the exhaust air blowing out of the unit cooler than room temperature? - Yes

Does water come out the condensation drain (not overflow) outside where it goes when the heater is operating? - For this I put a bowl to catch water and that way I will know.
